# Detect/Proxy changes to an object after its construction when there are async actions in it's factory/constructor

Tags: javascript

If I am trapping changes to an object using a Proxy, how do I also capture changes that occur asynchronously in the constructor/factory?

EDIT: I cannot modify the classes/factories to cooperate with the observation but I can modify the `observe` function.

```js
const observe = (target) => new Proxy({
  set(target, propKey, value) {
    if (target[propKey] === value) {
      return;
    }
    target[propKey] = value; 
    console.log('updated')
  },
})
```

When using the following it doesn't capture the async changes

```
class Foo {
  bar = 'initial'

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => this.bar = 'updated', 1000)
  }
}

observe(new Foo())
```

similarly

```
function createFoo() {
  const state = {
    bar: 'initial'
  }

  setTimeout(() => state.bar = 'updated', 1000)

  return state
}

observe(createFoo())
```

I realise the proxy is a new object and the factory/constructor is targeting the original object. As a result I have had success patching all the properties on the original object with getters/setters, intercepting changes to the current object instance. Of course new properties added to the object don't work without polling the object for property additions.

Is there a proxy based solution or is getters/setters + polling the only option?

Comment: If you can change the signature of `observe`, you could mess with the `Foo` constructor by injecting the proxy as `this`. Doesn't work for factories though. Getters/setters seem most promising here. Reasonable code shouldn't add new properties afterwards anyway.

Comment: Is [this](https://pastebin.com/1VcKkQur) something you want?

Comment: @Yousaf I'm pretty sure the OP cannot modify the classes/factories to cooperate with the observation

Comment: @Bergi, ignoring factories - how would I adjust the signature of `observe` to replace `this` with the Proxy?

Comment: @DavidAlsh I was thinking of `Reflect.construct` to inject a custom object for the `this` value (i.e. `createObserved(Foo, [...args])`), but nevermind that doesn't work properly (or not as well as `class Foo extends Observable {}` could). What you still can do is `Foo.prototype = new Proxy(Foo.prototype, …);` to observe assignments to new properties, but it's getting uglier and uglier.